# What is the correct string format specifier for integer in fmt.Printf?

Tags: go

```
var count int = 5
fmt.Printf("count:%i\n", count)
```

Its output is

```
count:%!i(int=5)
```

What is  the correct format specifier so that the output is

```
count:5
```

I look up the package `fmt`'s method `Printf` in Go's package website, but it doesn't say about the syntax for a format specifier. Where can I find the syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's [right there at the top of the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/). Sure, it's not repeated for the `Printf` documentation, but it's, well, right there are the top of the page :-/ This is a common pattern for Go documentation by the way.

Comment: we should try to use the documentation more than stack overflow... :( but there we are at the top of the google search in stack overflow.. :(

Answer (score 30):

`%d` is the format specifier for base 10 integers (what you typically want) a full listing of fmt's format specifiers can be found here; https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

```
var count int = 5
fmt.Printf("count:%d\n", count)
// prints count:5
```

Answer (score 17):

`%d` is the format specifier for integer. However, You can use `%v` to print the `value` of the variable in default format, no matter what the data type is.

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    //prints Hello 1 0.5 {Hello}
    fmt.Printf("%v %v %v %v", "Hello", 1, 0.5, struct{ v string }{"Hello"})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also simply opt for the [Println](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) function:

```
fmt.Println("count:", count)
```